# FTX API 'Missing parameter market' Python

Tags: python

```
s= requests.Session()
url = "https://ftx.com/api/orders"
ts = int(time.time()*1000)

params={
          "market": "DOT-PERP",
          "side": "buy",
          "price": 31,
          "type": "limit",
          "size": 0.5,
          "reduceOnly": False,
          "ioc": False,
          "postOnly": False,
          "clientId": None
        }

request=requests.Request("POST",url,params=params)

prepared = request.prepare()

signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'.encode()

signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(),signature_payload,'sha256').hexdigest()

request.headers = {'FTX-KEY':api_key,'FTX-SIGN':signature,'FTX-TS':str(ts)}

r = s.send(request.prepare())
r.json()
```

*RESPONSE {'success': False, 'error': 'Missing parameter market'}*

Traying to send and order, cant find whats missing, market parameter is loaded in params

Comment: The "-PERP" stands for perpetual future contract in your case DOT contract did you check that this is accessible for trading with FTX ?

Comment: thanks for the answerd, yes i checked that, it exists and trayed others tickets too, same response...

Comment: Well it looks like you don't add the actual payload but rather its signature try adding 
if prepared.body:
            signature_payload += prepared.body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = requests.Session()
url = "https://ftx.com/api/orders"
ts = int(time.time()*1000)

params = {
          "market": "DOT-PERP",
          "side": "buy",
          "price": 31,
          "type": "limit",
          "size": 0.5,
          "reduceOnly": False,
          "ioc": False,
          "postOnly": False,
          "clientId": None
        }

request = requests.Request("POST",url,params=params)

prepared = request.prepare()

signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'.encode()

if prepared.body:
   signature_payload += prepared.body

signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(),signature_payload,'sha256').hexdigest()

request.headers = {'FTX-KEY':api_key,'FTX-SIGN':signature,'FTX-TS':str(ts)}

r = s.send(request.prepare())
r.json()
```

Comment: thanks you very much! adding body to signature_payload was missing from my code! it worked!

Comment: Hi @RamiroLopez glad I could assist would you mind marking my post as a valid answer tx